# How to set the key of the JDBC source connector (kafka)?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm reading data from a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database table using a `Kafka Source JDBC connector` and publishing it to the topic `test-mysql-petai`.

The database table has 2 fields where `Id` is the primary key:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need the value of the `id` field to be the Key of the topic. I tried adding a transformation to the jdbc connector properties.

JDBCConnector.properties:

```
name=jdbc-source-connector    
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1   
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?user=dins&password=pw&serverTimezone=UTC
table.whitelist=petai 
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id    
schema.pattern=""    
transforms=createKey,extractInt    
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey    
transforms.createKey.fields=id    
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key    
transforms.extractInt.field=id    
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
```

But, when I read the keys and values using a consumer, I get following:

```
Key = {"schema":{"type":"int32","optional":false},"payload":61} 
Value ={"id":61,"name":"ttt"}
```

I need to get the following:

```
Key = 61    
Value ={"id":61,"name":"ttt"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you consume mesages? And please provide the following properties: `key.converter`, `value.converter`, `key.converter.schemas.enable`, `value.converter.schemas.enable`

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander  

To test this I used the default kafka-console-consumer.sh script that comes with kafka.

 `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-mysql-jdbc-petai --from-beginning` 

Did not pass any additional parameters when running the script. Do I need to add the ones you mentioned?

Comment: Try to set `"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false"`

Comment: I tried it, but still getting the same.

Comment: For the latest messages too?

Comment: It's working now. :) In addition to what you mention it also needed the other properties you mentioned at the first.
 `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false`

Also, as you said it is only changing the keys of the new messages, even though I ran the consumer again. May I know why?

Comment: Yes, but it seems other properties already have these values.
Kafka stores messages in accordance with the retention policy, so every time when you consume topic from beggining you consume the same messages (which were produced with a schema)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I'm not sure whether the other properties are having the values, because it failed to give the expected outcome without, them.
Following link is about JDBC sink connector, it says either to have them all or not have any. [https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/574] . I'm really new to Kafka, so do not have much idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to include a schema to keys, you can tell Kafka Connect about it by setting `key.converter.schemas.enable=false`.

For a detailed explanation, please see [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Converters and Serialization Explained by Robin Moffatt](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas).